# How to manipulate the data return in Json Callback

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-3

i have a very simple autocomplete textbox to show the entries.. i want to manipulate the data return in callback function.. i am not sure how to do that .. please help..

## UPDATED jquery code

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#txtAC').autocomplete({

```
    source: '@Url.Action("ShowTitle","Home")',
    dataType: 'json',
    parse: function (data) {
        var rows = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            rows[i] = { data: data[i], value: data[i].Title, result: data[i].Title };
        }
        return rows;
    },
    formatItem: function (item) {
        return item.Title + '(' + item.Body + ')';
    },


});
```

});

## here is my controller action which return the title & description

```
 public JsonResult ShowTitle(string term)
        {
            var result = (from t in db.DBEntries
                          where t.Title.Contains(term)
                          select new { Title = t.Title, Body = t.Body }).ToList();
            return Json(result.ToArray(),JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

its showing me the Title in autoComplete but i want to show like this 
Title - Description

## seeking help...

Comment: By "Description" do you mean "Body"?

Comment: yup... @rockinthesixstring: he rocked the boat ...

Comment: when i am trying to parse the data, its not even showing me the Title field... please have a look at the updated jquery code and let me know.. many thx...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
return {value: item.Title + ' - ' + item.Description}
```

Comment: on the same note: when i am trying another trick here ...parse: its not working ...can you have a look at the updated code..plz

Comment: I'm actually not a jQuery guru... I do know string concatenation.